# uninstalling content package is grayed out

Tags: package, uninstallation, aem

I replicated packages from my author to my publish and installed the packages on the publisher.

Now I want to uninstall the packages on my publisher to replicate the new packages from the author to the publisher.

This is where the problem lies, the uninstall option is grayed out for all my packages.
Anybody got any ideas what I can do to uninstall them?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick test. If you reinstall the package directly on Publish the uninstall option will then be available. I haven't found why installing on publish through author activation of a package does not enable the uninstall option directly.

Depending on what you are specifically trying to do and what you are experiencing, building the package from author and Re-replicating will update the package on publish without the need to uninstall the package from publish first.

Answer (score 0):

You can only uninstall a package if a snapshot is available. Installing via the author replication does not create a snapshot. Therefore you cannot uninstall the package.